# Adding new elements to mysql tables through html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-update

I am trying to add new elements to my mysql table through html
So far I've got this

```
    <form action="MyCurrentFile.php" method="post" >
         Artist Name
         <input type="text" name="addingnewelement" <br/> 
         <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" />
     </form>
```

and this

```
   <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $addingelement=$_POST['addingnewelement'];
         $mysqli->select_db("names", $names);

         echo("this code is running");
         $sql='INSERT INTO names (nameValue) VALUES ('.$addingelement.')';
         $mysqli->query($sql, $mysqli);
         $mysqli->close($mysqli);
    }
    ?>
```

Is there anything on my syntax wrong? the code does not give me any error, all that happens is that I press my button to update with my input but nothing happens.

Comment: first close the input tag, if you have not closed in your script.

Comment: Please put "if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {" instead "if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {"

Answer (score 1):

you need to put hte artist name as the label and close the input, and make the name of the submit button the same as in your other page.

```
<form action="MyCurrentFile.php" method="post" >
   <label for="artistName">Artist Name</label>
   <input type="text" id="artistName" name="addingnewelement" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

also your sql query is wrong - it should be:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO names (nameValue) VALUES ('".$addingelement."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is wrong. Please replace this live:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO names (nameValue) VALUES ('$addingelement')";
```

Answer (score 0):

the submit button name is Submit with capital S but you are using isset($_POST['submit']) with small s
correct this. it will work..
and also if    $sql='INSERT INTO names (nameValue) VALUES ('.$addingelement.')'; not working then try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO names (nameValue) VALUES ('".$addingelement."')";
```